# SalesForce : Redirecting the URL to Salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Here is my requirement.

When i enter my domain Like "ww.abc.com"  in the Url of a browser. then it should redirect to the force.com site Url like "newdeveloper.force.com" site created in salesforce. but in the url it should show me as "www.abc.com".
the mapping should be done in back-end.

Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You need a DNS CNAME record added in your DNS server config to point your www.abc.com domain name at the YOURSITE.force.com domain.

Support at your DNS host should be able to help you.